# React "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I'm React newbie and struggling. Following snippet gives the following error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'creationDate' of
>   undefined".

If I move code from populateTableRows and creationDate functions inside render, everything works nicely. SurveyList gets it's data from another component. I know this is pretty ugly component and all other suggestions are welcome too, but I'm mostly interested in this one particular error.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table, Tr, Td } from 'reactable';

class SurveyList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSaved: false,
      surveys: []
    };
    this.creationDate = this.creationDate.bind(this);
    this.populateTableRows = this.populateTableRows.bind(this);    
  }

  creationDate (obj){
    return new Date(obj._id.time).toISOString().slice(0,10);
  }

  populateTableRows(surveys){
    var surveyRows = [];
    surveys.forEach(function(obj){
      surveyRows.push(
        <Tr key={obj.surveyId}>
          <Td column="SurveyId">{obj.surveyId}</Td>
          <Td column="Survey name">{obj.surveyName}</Td>
          <Td column="Creation date">{this.creationDate(obj)}</Td>
          <Td column=""><ModalDialog key={obj.surveyId}
                                     survey={obj}
          /></Td>
        </Tr>
      );
    });
    return surveyRows;
  }

  render() {
    var surveys = Array.from(this.props.surveys);
    var surveyRows = this.populateTableRows(surveys);
    return (
      <Table className="table" id="table" sortable={true} filterable={['SurveyId', 'Survey name', 'Creation date']}>
        {surveyRows}
      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this has more do with scope and closures perhaps?  Try the following `surveys.forEach(() => { ....`.  An anonymous function will hold the scope you are after for the `this.creationDate` call.  Check this ebook out too: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures

Comment: Thanks, I definitely have to read that.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @ctrlplusb is correct. When you use a `function` keyword as you have done in your `surveys.forEach` call, its contents get a new scope - and therefore a new `this`, which is undefined as it belongs to no object. There are several solutions.

The prettiest is to use the new fat arrow ("lexical `this`") syntax available in ES2015 through Babel. It creates a function that maintains the scope in which it was defined. E.g.:

```
surveys.forEach( obj => surveyRows.push(/* ... */) );
```

However, the simplest is to use the [second argument that `forEach` takes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is the `this` to use:

```
surveys.forEach( function ( obj ) {
  surveyRows.push(/* ... */);
}, this );
```